# Names of all classes that can be argument to a method in C++

Tags: c++, oop, methods

Let's have two classes Rectangle and Circle.

Let the class Display implements method draw(Rectangle r) and draw(Circle c) and maybe some others. I would like to have a static method that with return a list of all classes that may be subject to the draw method. i.e. {"Rectangle", "Circle" }.

Comment: "I would like to have..." - a question. This seems like a *task*, not a question. Are you asking if the language provides such an intrinsic feature? If so, the answer is no; you have to provide it (and it won't be trivial).

Comment: What for?   -- C++ does not provide reflection / type inspection. There are external tools - like intellisense in IDE's or  VisualAssist - that can acquire *a good approximation of the data* this question would require through static code analysis. I've never come across one having this exact feature, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without building in special facilities yourself. Names in general are not stored in your executable in a compiled language like C++.